# Computing two integrals - per-partes?

Tags: definite-integrals

I start with integrals and attempting to figure out these two integrals, but can't move from a spot

1. $\int x^2 lnx dx$
2. $\int \frac{lnx}{\sqrt[3]{x}}dx$

The first example - it doesn't look so complicated, but I just can't get the right result. And the second looks pretty complicated, not sure what do to first there.

Thank you

Comment: For the second one, use the "rationalizing substitution" $ \ u^3 \ = \ x \ $ , then keep in mind that $ \ \ln (u^3) \ = \ 3 \ \ln u \ $ .

Answer (score 0):

I will do the first one: Using integration by parts

$$ \int x^2 \ln x dx  = \frac{1}{3} \int  \ln x d(x^3) = \frac{1}{3} \ln x x^3 - \frac{1}{3} \int x^3 d(\ln x) = \frac{1}{3} \ln x x^3 - \frac{1}{3} \int x^2 dx $$

$$ = \frac{1}{3} \ln x \  x^3 - \frac{1}{9}x^3 + C$$

Comment: I made a small edit because your text was breaking to the next line at an awkward spot in the equation.